# how to send parameter to script for "sed"?

Tags: bash, sed, ubuntu-12.04

I am using "sed -i 's/original/new/g' $gg" in script but when at terminal, using parameter when i write **./test echo print** , then error appears:

```
sed : no input files
```

here is my attempt:

FIle name : **test**

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i 's/$original/$new/g' $gg
```

And gg file:

```
#!/bin/bash
ns="ns1.cyberciti.biz ns2.cyberciti.biz ns3.cyberciti.biz"
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=' '
read -a dnsservers <<< "${ns}"
IFS="$OIFS"
echo ${dnsservers[1]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When gg is the filename, do not use $gg but gg.
When the filename is stored in the var gg, and the var is exported, test it with

```
echo "File gg=${gg}"
```

before your sed command.

When you add the line `set -x` you will see that the variables original and new aren't replaced. That's caused by the single quotes, you must end the single quote, give the var in double quotes and start with a single quote again. This method for both vars.
The sed line will become

```
sed -i 's/'"$original"'/'"$new"'/g' gg
```

Optional you can put curly braces around the vars:

```
sed -i 's/'"${original}"'/'"${new}"'/g' gg
```

Comment: sorry for late reply i was in class room. I am now getting this error: sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression